# Mosfet operation wrt AC signals

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, ac

I am trying to understand about the Mosfet operation.
It would be great if someone could help me get answers to these questions -

1. What happens to an AC signal (DC+ small AC signal) if it is applied to the gate of a MOS which is biased in Linear mode.
   In the saturation mode, the output at the drain/source can be found using the small signal analysis mos model. 
   In the Linear mode, how do we analyse this? As the mos behaves as resistor here the output automatically should be DC+ AC component? What happens to the gain here?
   From the transfer characteristics of, say CS amplifier, it is seen that the output at drain is small and dvo/dvi is small.
2. What would happen to the gain and other parameters for a circuit which is biased in saturation with an Ideal current source as seen in the image, for small signal analysis.

[image: Mos Bias with current source]

vo (node) DC value would be Vdd-I.Rd
Also with an assumption that device is huge (KW/L = huge), vs (node) DC component can be taken as -Vth.
What would be the AC component of voltages at these nodes? Will there be any gain here?
Also, If we have a big bypass cap at vs node, then the analysis would be the same as that for a CS amplifier. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the linear region we can calculate the transconductance like in the saturation region. 
   $$
   \frac{\partial I_D}{\partial V_{gs}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial V_{gs}} K^\prime \frac WL \left[ (V_{gs} - V_T)V_{ds} - V_{ds^2}/2\right] = K^\prime \frac WL V_{ds}
   $$
   Unfortunately the expression contains \$V_{ds}\$ which tells us that the transistor behaves like a resistor and the model is not very useful.

Nevertheless, we can calculate the gain which results in
\$A_v = K^\prime \frac WL V_{ds} R_{out} \$ so we can calculate it, if we make an assumption about \$V_{ds}\$. E.g. we could bias the transistor at \$V_{ds} = 100mV\$ and continue from there.

2. Since the current is fixed by the current source and the resistors are fixed as well, there will be no small signal gain. We have a gain of about 1 from Vsig to Vs, since the transistor acts as a source follower. Vo will stay constant.

Comment: 1. So since the Vds in Linear mode would be considerably small, the gain in turn would be small or maybe less than 1 as well.
Hence we would choose to be in Saturation and maintain it that way for the entire operation range. Is that correct?
      
2. So if we bias using a current sink, then the small signal analysis using the output res. of current sink can be done right? OR if we place a bypass cap at top of current source, which would act as a short at operation freq. and introduce an AC ground at bottom of Rs. In  that case the gain would be the same as CS amp. with source degeneration?

Comment: 1. Saturation is usually preferred, however in some applications linear mode is used, too. Even if the gain is low another stage (OpAmp) could compensate for it. 2. For AC a different behavior could be obtained by using a capacitor in parallel to the current source. It would be better to start with a stage that fits the purpose.

Comment: I had another query wrt linear & sat mode.
From the Id vs. Vgs characteristics, we see that for a fixed Vds the current is more as the Vgs increases(as the res. in the linear mode is inv. proportional to Vgs), so that means for high current applications we should prefer Linear mode? But since the higher current would mean more drop across the pull up res./load leading to less or no voltage gain, we wouldn't want to use in voltage amplification cases. Is that correct?

Comment: Voltage and current amplification is usually done in different stages. A stage that amplifies the voltage is followed by a stage that acts as a current amplifier.